# Hiding textbox in asp.net when click on button

Tags: c#, asp.net

The problem is i have three buttons in page with 4 text boxes,
when first button clicked it will update the data,second insert and third delete

The requirement is on page load it shows all text boxes that's fine. when delete button clicked i need only one text box instead of all in the same page only.

I need both 4 text boxes and one text box on same page according to my requirement.

```
  <asp:Label runat="server" Text="Userid:" ID="lab1" ></asp:Label>
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" BorderStyle="Groove" ForeColor="Red"  EnableViewState="False" ></asp:TextBox>
                        <asp:Button ID="btn_delete" runat="server" Text="delete" OnClick="btn_delete_Click"  ForeColor="DodgerBlue" CausesValidation="false" OnClientClick="return confirm('Are you sure you want delete')"  />
```

note: I've refer some links and tutorials but i didn't get solution.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try to put your code in `if(!isPostBack)`. If you want to show all the `textboxes` to be shown while `page load` then try to put this in `!isPostBack` block. After resubmitting form this code will not be executed. This block only execute one time the `page load`. When you click on the `delete` button your form is posted back to the server, so the condition false this time in `page load` event.

```
if(!isPostBack)
{
    Textbox1.Visible =true;
    Textbox2.Visible =true;
    Textbox3.Visible =true;
    Textbox4.Visible =true;
}
```

And on `Delete` button click

```
protected void btn_delete_Click(object sender, eventargs e)
{
    Textbox2.Visible =false;
    Textbox3.Visible =false;
    Textbox4.Visible =false;
}
```